# Proper way to "reflash" pendrive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have been handed a PILZ flash drive from my friend, because it is apparently broken - indeed, it is.
Connecting it to my computer instantly installed it's driver as a "XXXXXXXX U177CONTROLLER" device with 0MB of space, trying to view it results in a "Please insert media" message from Windows.
I've read around, and found no fix for almost 2 hours now and I'm left totally clueless.

Answer (score 0):

The ***proper way*** to handle any defective flash drive/SD card is to...
...**throw it away**.

They are simply not worth the effort once they start to go wrong.